# Is it necessary to place this line in every REST API for user authentication?

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, passport.js, restify

I would like to add user login authentication for my REST API server which was implemented in node.js restify.

I intend to use this module `restify-ensure-login`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-ensure-login

I want all the API functions to require user login authentication. Am I right to say that every API must contain this line `ensureLoggedIn('/login'),`?

Something like below?

```
app.get('/settings',
  ensureLoggedIn('/login'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('settings', { user: req.user });
  });
```

Is there some way to have this line `ensureLoggedIn('/login'),` appear once only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic use-case for middleware:

```
// Runs before every downstream route
app.use(ensureLoggedIn('/login'));

app.get('/settings', function(req, res) {
  res.render('settings', { user: req.user });
});
```

http://restify.com/#common-handlers-serveruse

Comment: Just make sure that the login-related routes are declared before the `ensureLoggedIn()` middleware is.